# Application_Start in WCF Web Services App

Tags: asp.net, wcf

The Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs was being called in my WCF web services application when it was running under ASP.NET 2.

It has been recompiled with the .NET 4 framework and it now runs under ASP.NET 4. However, that method is not ever being called.

Anyone know what's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I am using WCF without .svc files in .NET 4.0.

I have seen an oddity that sometimes this requires creating APP_Code folder in the root of your site and copying flbal.asax and global.asax.cs to it. Give it a try.

Comment: Mine's a web application, however -- not a web site.